# Send key does not work in window service shows access denied error

Tags: c#

I am working on window service. Service access the ie object using `ShDocVw` object in c# to get currently opened service window object and fill the value into the fields.

Problem is the ie page contains dropdown list which have some values like for country list if you did not find your country in list there is link beside the drop down list by service we have to click on it and it has search box, the country value should be filled into the box using service automatically with out user interaction.

The window which is opened for search is `window.showModalDialog(uri[, arguments][, options]);` window which stops the current thread and shdocvw object does not found the modal window object in

```
foreach (SHDocVw.WebBrowser ie1 in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
```

right now my issue is sendkey functionality shows error of

> access denied

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(value + "{ENTER}");
```

Comment: Side note: why don't you use headless browser? Convincing UI program to correctly run in service session is not trivial (and definitely not supported).

Comment: but my application purpose is to fill the web form opened in IE explorer.